# How to position a custom anchor in a custom TikZ shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I want to draw a "system dynamics" flow chart, roughly looking like this [random image](http://distance-educator.com/wp-content/uploads/Figure5_FlwoDiagram_SabaAndShearer.jpg). The dark grey valve-like boxes are for `rates`, while the grey rectangles are for `levels`.

I managed to define a shape that looks fine, but I struggle to modify the `east` anchor, so that it always lands on the valve's intersection point.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{rate}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}

  \savedanchor\centerpoint{\pgf@x=0cm \pgf@y=0cm}

  \saveddimen\halfheight{
    \pgf@x=\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgfshapeinnerysep
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{.5\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xa\pgf@x=\pgf@xa\fi}

  \anchor{east}{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@x by5pt
    \pgf@y=\pgf@ya \advance\pgf@y by\halfheight
  }

  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % offset of valve part
    \pgf@xc=10pt \pgf@yc=4pt%

    % construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{-\pgf@yc}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathclose%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,shape=rate,fill=gray!10,inner sep=5pt] at (0,0) (fres) {\ttfamily FRES};
\draw[black] (fres.east) -- +(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Rate symbol with current (red) and desired (green) location of the shape's east anchor]

The documentation for all the `\pgf@` magic and plain TeX is still pretty opaque to me. How can I put the `east` anchor where I want it?

Comment: Part of the problem is that TikZ is entirely written using plain TeX (for compatibility) so avoids things like \dimexpr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The y location of the east anchor is simply the average of the top and bottom y values.  The x location depends on the relative height of the left and right sides of the valve section, so I made the right side half the height of the left side, putting the crossing point 2/3 of the way across.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{rate}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}

  \savedanchor\centerpoint{\pgfpointorigin}

  \anchor{east}{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \advance\pgf@x by8pt
    \pgf@y=\dimexpr 0.5\pgf@ya + 0.5\pgf@yb
  }

  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % offset of valve part
    \pgf@xc=12pt \pgf@yc=\dimexpr 0.25\pgf@yb - 0.25\pgf@ya

    % construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{-\pgf@yc}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathclose%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,shape=rate,fill=gray!10,inner sep=5pt] at (0,0) (fres) {\ttfamily FRES};
\draw[black] (fres.east) -- +(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: new shape]