# How to define new anchor border in new shapes with tikz-pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, shapes

I'm trying to build a libray of symbols by means of defining new shapes in pgf-tikz. To be honest, it's being a enormous task for me because I don't understand lot of things of code to do it. Fortunately, thanks to these web, and @marmot, step by step I almost achieve the task. But now, I have problems with anchors border. Here the code and its corresponding self-explanatory result.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,makeshape}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{contador.tex}

\makeatletter

\def\gap{0pt}
\newlength{\an@ctdordiv} \an@ctdordiv=5mm

%% Anchor path:

\def\generalanchor{} % No es necesario, el nodo no llevará texto.

%% Background path:

\def\contdivborder{ % Obtiene la caja de texto correcta:

  % La parte anterior no es necesaria, no llevará texto el nodo
  % Triángulo izquierdo:
  %
  \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-\an@ctdordiv}{-\an@ctdordiv}}
                          {\pgfpoint{ \an@ctdordiv}{ \an@ctdordiv}}

  \ifx\tikz@fillcolor\empty
    \pgfusepath{stroke,clip}
  \else
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\tikz@fillcolor}
    % La opción clip evita los picos del triángulo sobresaliendo.
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke,clip}
  \fi
  %
  % Línea diagonal
  %
  \pgfsetbeveljoin
  \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\an@ctdordiv}{-\an@ctdordiv}}
  \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{ \an@ctdordiv}{ \an@ctdordiv}}

}

%% Declaración de la forma:

\pgfdeclareshape{contador divisionario}{

  \setpaths{\generalanchor}{\contdivborder}

  \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{
      \pgf@x = \ctbnex
      \pgf@y = \ctbney
      \advance\pgf@x by \gap
      \advance\pgf@y by \gap
      \mincorrect{\pgf@x}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
      \mincorrect{\pgf@y}{\pgfshapeminheight}
      \advance\pgf@x\pgfshapeouterxsep
      \advance\pgf@y\pgfshapeouterysep
  }

  % Anchors:
  \anchor{c}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=0pt}
  %
  \anchor{u}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y= \an@ctdordiv}
  \anchor{d}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=0pt \pgf@y=-\an@ctdordiv}
  \anchor{r}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \an@ctdordiv \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{l}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\an@ctdordiv \pgf@y=0pt}
  %
  \anchor{ur}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \an@ctdordiv \pgf@y= \an@ctdordiv}
  \anchor{dr}{\centerpoint \pgf@x= \an@ctdordiv \pgf@y=-\an@ctdordiv}
  \anchor{ul}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\an@ctdordiv \pgf@y= \an@ctdordiv}
  \anchor{dl}{\centerpoint \pgf@x=-\an@ctdordiv \pgf@y=-\an@ctdordiv}

}

\makeatother


\end{filecontents*}

\tikzset{
    st texto/.style={
        font=\scriptsize\tiny,align=center,anchor=north,
        black,inner sep=0.0em
    },
    st valvula/.style={
        node contents={},
        draw,minimum width=3mm,minimum height=2.85mm,line width=0.1mm,inner sep=0em,scale=2
    },
    st linea nodo/.style={line width=0.1mm,latex-,orange,shorten >= 0.5em},
}

\input{contador.tex}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm,remember picture]

  %%

    \path (0,0) node (wrong) [%
    contador divisionario,st valvula,
    fill=cyan!50,line width=1mm
  ];

  \draw[st linea nodo] (wrong.r) -- ++(0:10) node[st texto] {r};

  \node[circle,minimum size=4mm,draw=red] (circwrong) at (wrong.r) {};
  \node[st texto] (txtwrong) at ([shift={(10,-5)}]wrong.r) {
    anchor in\\ the center\\ of the line\\ I don't need\\ this!
  };
  \draw[-latex,line width=0.1mm] (txtwrong) edge[out=90,in=-20] (circwrong);

  %%

    \path (40,0) node (correct) [%
    contador divisionario,st valvula,
    fill=cyan!50,line width=1mm
  ];

  \draw[st linea nodo] ([shift={(0.5,0)}]correct.r) -- ++(0:10) node[st texto] {r};

  \node[circle,minimum size=4mm,draw=green] (circcorrect) at (correct.r) {};
  \node[st texto] (txtcorrect) at ([shift={(10,-5)}]correct.r) {
      anchor in\\ the border\\ of the line\\ What I want!
  };
  \draw[-latex,line width=0.1mm] (txtcorrect) edge[out=90,in=-20] (circcorrect);

  %%

    \path (80,0) node (correct2) [%
    contador divisionario,st valvula,
    fill=cyan!50,line width=2mm
  ];

  \draw[st linea nodo] ([shift={(1,0)}]correct2.r) -- ++(0:10) node[st texto] {r};

  \node[circle,minimum size=4mm,draw=green] (circcorrect2) at (correct2.r) {};
  \node[st texto] (txtcorrect2) at ([shift={(10,-5)}]correct2.r) {
    anchor in\\ the border\\ of the line\\ What I want!
  };
  \draw[-latex,line width=0.1mm] (txtcorrect2) edge[out=90,in=-20] (circcorrect2);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've been consulting many examples but I don't understand anything. Please, can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One can use \pgfpointorigin to find the center, no saved anchor needed.  Typically \southwest and \northeast are the only saved anchors.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222424/circuitikz-dac-and-adc-shapes/223634?r=SearchResults&s=4|9.8061#223634 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249722/how-to-position-a-custom-anchor-in-a-custom-tikz-shape/249761?r=SearchResults&s=9|9.0735#249761.

Comment: How about `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum width=3mm,minimum height=2.85mm,fill=cyan!50,line width=1mm,
inner sep=0em,outer sep=0.25mm,scale=2,path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.south west) 
-- (path picture bounding box.north east);}] (test){};
\draw[latex-] (test.east) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`? If you look at `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex` you see that there the outer sep is added to the anchors. Maybe you will be better off if you start with a shape from there.

Comment: @kormylo Thanks for \pgfpointorigin comment. With respect to examples, the problem is that I need symbols which are normalized, and therefore they must have fixed dimensions. I started this symbols inheriting other shapes but I decided not using that.

Comment: @marmot Thanks again. I built many symbols using tikz commands and they work properly. However, as I use them to make hydraulic diagrams with many symbols, compilation time is expensive. Due to that fact, I want to design these symbols in plain tex and pgf commands.

Comment: I understand. But what I do not understand is why you do not just copy an existing shape, inherit the anchors from there, and be fine.

Comment: @marmot May be due to my ignorance. The example above is a minimal example, but there other more complex shapes, and for me having fixed dimensions is very important (only I need they are scalable and this works).

Comment: Moreover, the shapes have especific anchors different from usual.